# Why does Developer Story not use the email address under Email Settings?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, developer-story

I changed my email recently under Email Settings. However, the PDF export of the Developer Story uses my old address. Is there a reason for this? Is there a different place where I need to change my email address?

**Where I changed  my email address:**

[image]

Comment: You know there is a second email box further down that is used only for Stack Overflow, yeah?

Comment: I did not! Guess As soon as I saw the first email input box I didn't consider that there would be more than one in the same area.

Comment: Let us all know if that changes what shows in the developer story (I don't actually know, I just noticed it was different).

Comment: The 2nd input area did the trick. That is the email address that shows.

Comment: Whether or not the second box helps this is a good example of a UI/UX that may be hard for users to understand.  There may be multiple reasons for multiple fields for email addresses.  This post shows this can be confusing...

Comment: @JonH Agreed, if there are multiple email inputs they should probably be grouped together in some way so you see both at the same time. Most sites and services tend to use a single address, not multiple, which is where the confusion came from.

Comment: I personally think it'd make more sense for the section that only affects Stack Overflow to be bumped to the top when editing on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't see how this is a hard ux to understand. You edit the developer story in the edit developer story form, and you edit your profile within the edit profile form. they're two completely separate things. The only way it would be confusing is if the user doesn't understand that the two things are different, which i can see happening if every new user is still being sent to their developer story on sign up rather than their profile.

Comment: @KevinB The email for the developer story is set in a separate area from the developer story.

Comment: hmm.. I don't even see where i can change my email other than at the screenshot you provided. (other than maybe using a different login, i use google)