# How can I change the email of the printed version of resume?

Tags: support, status-completed, developer-story

I am trying to change the email that is on the printed version of the resume. There is a section "Email Settings" under Edit Profile and Settings. I have changed the my current email from there, But it doesn't work. It is still showing the email address that I used for the login.

How can change the email address on printed version?

Comment: you're not alone: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359400/why-does-developer-story-not-use-the-email-address-under-email-settings and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343760/make-it-easier-to-set-email-for-developer-story

Comment: There are  lot of email settings involved ...

Comment: @rene There was another email box way down the Edit Email Settings section. I did change the email. Nothing happened. Now that email(2nd) edit option gone. :(

Comment: That is strange. I re-opened this, it needs an SE dev to see which option should be used then. Sorry that I can't be of any help.

Comment: @seal is this still an issue for you? You are changing the email in the correct place.

Comment: @jisoo nope. working fine for me now. not sure what happened then.

Comment: @seal i believe we rolled out a fix after you posted, but we never got around to answering. thanks for confirming!

Comment: @jisoo ahh !! Sorry about that .

Comment: @seal our fault, not yours :).

Comment: Ha ha ha ... I got that .